# 403 when making a request with data post through a tor socks proxy

Tags: python, macos, request, urllib, tor

This is my code and the title explain everything what are my mistake?
my developer is python 3.4
and I am working in a macos
I search for uses whit post data and tor socket proxy but no find anything  a trow whidout the proxy works but I need the proxy

```
import os,ssl
if (not os.environ.get('PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY', '') and
getattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context', None)):
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

if os.name == 'nt':
    import ctypes
    kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32

import  urllib.request
import socks
import socket


socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
url = 'https://roomlister.stream.highwebmedia.com/session/start/'
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
values = {'categories':'f,c','num':'120'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode() 
request.add_header('Cache-Control','max-age=0')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request,data)
print (response.read())
```

the error

```
http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: As the message says, HTTP 403 means you are not allowed to access that resource. Either you did not log in or you did log in, but don't have the required permission.

Comment: Without the proxy the code is working very well. I  think the data is not being uploaded to the post